# how to run node app.js on production environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express and hosting my website on Cloudflare. It work well on localhost by command `node app.js` but when I publish it to cloudflare, only index.html is showing. Whenever I change the url to https://domainname/api/users or https://domainname/api/users/1, it is still showing index.html. I have tried on Insonmia to request GET from https://domainname/api/users but the response is index.html. Everything work well on localhost.

Here is my code on app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Our express server is up on port ${port}`);
});

const users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'user1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'user2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'user3' },
];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/api/users', (req, res) => {
    res.send(users);
});

app.get('/api/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    const user = users.find((c) => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (!user) res.status(404).send('Error 404: Users not found.');
    res.send(user);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </meta>
    <title>hello</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>hello world</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  },
  "name": "hello",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `node app.js` to start script in `package.json`. (So your hosting service (cloudfare) will run that script to start your project.)

Try the following code in your package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  },
  "name": "hello",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",

    "start": "node index.js"

  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try adding new script called `"start": "node index.js"` to your package.json. 
This resolve your problem!